# No symbol "color" in current context. GDB

Tags: gdb, watch

I am trying to debug code using gdb, but when I try to watch my variable color it say this

```
No symbol "color" in current context.
```

The variable is a int and is clearly in the scope. the code is as follow

```
int color=0;

if(color==0)
  color=1;
```

and my debugger is passed the declaration of the variable.

I am only doing, with a break point at the if(color==0)

```
(gdb) watch color
```

I might suspect the compiler or something, is that possible?

Edit : there is some issues with debugging in constructors with GDB

Comment: Please post a transcript of your interaction with GDB.  As is, it's impossible to say which of many possible things you may be doing wrong.

Comment: Is the program compiled with debugging symbols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you're passing the `-g` flag to gcc when you compile your code. You should also pass `-O0` to ensure that the compiler isn't optimizing your variable away.